# Unicode - Scala Print square root symbol

Tags: scala

I am using the

```
println("\u221A")
```

its printing something else .
[image]

REPL Output - Windows 7 64 bit

[image]

How to print  the square root symbol ?

Comment: Go on, give us a clue. What does it print instead? That way we might have a hope of working out what needs fixing.

Comment: As @Madoc says, it depends on your terminal, not OS. you should check your console setting or go for another terminal such as Tera Term of Putty. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators#Microsoft_Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code prints the square root symbol on my machine (MacOS X 10.11.5, iTerm2 3.0.20160604-nightly, zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0))

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> println("\u221A")
√
```

This may have to do with the charset of your console.

Note that you can alternatively do:

```
println("√")
```

because Scala source code is Unicode compatible.

Comment: Of course, if his browser has the same encoding issues as his terminal, this answer will look equally wrong ;-)